# Android, Xamarin, EditTexts: Disable the user from deleting the first letters

Tags: android, xamarin, android-edittext

I want the user to type in his or her Facebook account-link (don't have a better solution atm).

Now, when the user clicks the edittext it is supposed to say : "www.facebook.com/". Now the cursor is supposed to be at the END of the edittext (after the "/") and the user is not supposed to delete the first letters so that the "www.facebook.com/" stays exactly where it is. This will have the user to ONLY type in his or her facebook name and therefore connect the profile.

Is there a way of doing this?

Thank you :)

Comment: add a textview with `www.facebook.com/` to the left of EditText

Comment: Check out this link: https://medium.com/@ali.muzaffar/adding-a-prefix-to-an-edittext-2a17a62c77e1 I'am not aware of any "easy" solution at the moment, could be oen tho so i suggest you keep searching a bit.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko i did this. but the user can simple delete this line, also the cursor starts at the left of the facebook

Comment: @innomotionmedia Please add the Xamarin tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by using the event "TextChanged" and in your code validate if the size is big than your string, like that:

```
if (((EditText)sender).Text.Length >= 17)
{
  ((EditText)sender).Text = e.NewTextValue;
}
else
{
  ((EditText)sender).Text = "www.facebook.com/";
}
```

So if the value is bigger than your string you will replace that for the value, if not you just set the value with your string